# How to reshape a 1d array to a 3d array with diffrerent size of 2d arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to reshape this array: `np.array(np.arange(15))` to a 3d array that is built from a 3x3 array and a 3x2 array.

I've tried to do it with the reshape method but it didn't work.

I thought that maybe `reshape` can get a number of tuples maybe.
`a=np.array(np.arange(15)).reshape(1,((3,2),(3,3)))`
but I then I saw it cant.

How can I reshape it then? is there a nice way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a multidimensional array can't have dimensions with different size.

but if you want a tuple you will need to split the array in 2 parts, the first that match in size with the 3x3 array and the second that match the 3x2, at this point you'll have 2 one dimensional array, then reshape them

```
arr1 = arr1.reshape((3,3)) 
arr2 = arr2.reshape((3,2))

tuple = arr1, arr2
```